# wkhtmltopfd not working inshell_exec() in php

Tags: php

I am working on a project that runs `Docker` and `lando`.

I got stuck when converting the url into pdf through `wkhtmltopdf`.

Through `wkhtmltopdf`, the pdf is generated through a shell command but it's not working in `shell_exec()`.

For that, I have installed the libraries: `mikehaertl` and `snappy`.

In my system, `autoloader.php` also exits.

When I run this program:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("wkhtmltopdf  https://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I get the following error:

> sh1 wkhtmltopdf not found

On another hand, I have tried a different program:
`mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf`

```
$pdf = new Pdf(' https://www.google.com');
if (!$pdf->saveAs('/var/www/html/education-ict-toolkit/web/google.pdf')) {
    $error = $pdf->getError();
}
```

And I got the following error:

> mikehaertl not found